# HTML CSS Как сделать чтобы блок выходил за границы экрана но при этом горизонтального скролла не было?

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование, вёрстка, frontend

```css
.test_p {
  max-width: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  right: -50px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
  <title>Тест сайт</title>
</head>

<body>
  <p class="test_p">Текст</p>
</body>

</html>
```

Пробовал overflow: hidden; не работает, можете пожалуйста сказать как правильно или пример дать

Comment: Вам нужно предоставить пример того что вы сделали или пытаетесь сделать чтобы можно было помочь

Comment: html

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
        <title>Тест сайт</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p class="test_p">Текст</p>
    </body>
</html>
css
.test_p {
    max-width: 300px;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    right: -50px;
}

Comment: Отредактируйте ваш вопрос и добавьте код туда. А так, ваш overflow применяется для того элемента, которому установлен класс и действует он на данном элементе, а не на родительском. Т.е. в вашем p внутри, не будет скролла.

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего это то что вам нужно

```css
    .overflow {
        overflow: hidden;
        position: relative;
    }
    .test_p { 
        max-width: 300px; 
        position: absolute; 
        right: -50px;
    }
```

```html
    <div class = "overflow">
        <p class="test_p">Текст</p>
    </div>
```

Comment: А этот текст теперь можно будет сделать и слева и справа? и можно max-width убрать? или поставить другое значение

Comment: на счет лева и права да, на счет max-width по надобности